# how to implement regexp_substr in hive?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, oracle-sqldeveloper, hiveql

So i have an oracle query :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('BOND~CRR~CD~DAKAR_2299913320','[^~]+',1,3) FROM DUAL
```

from that query the result should be like : CD

now, my question is how to implement that query in hive, because from what i know, hive does not have REGEXP_SUBSTR syntax, so far what i have already try was :

```
select regexp_extract('BOND~CRR~CD~DAKAR_2299913320','[^~]+',0)
```

but the result was : BOND

when i change my query to :

```
select regexp_extract('BOND~CRR~CD~DAKAR_2299913320','[^~]+',2)
```

it was give a semanticExecption : wrong arguments '2'

so is there any way to implement that oracle query in hive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPLIT Function instead of REGEXP

```
select split('BOND~CRR~CD~DAKAR_2299913320','[\~]')[2]
```

For more details refer below link

https://dwgeek.com/hive-string-functions-examples.html/

Answer (score 0):

As described here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf the last argument is the index of capturing group.
You've got the `wrong arguments '2'` exception because in your example you didn't have any capture group (except the general 0)

REGEXP_SUBSTR works as expected, only one thing you have to fix is the regexp.
By example:

```
select regexp_extract('BOND~CRR~CD~DAKAR_2299913320','^[^~]*~[^~]*~([^~]*)~.*',1);
```

will give you the desired result.

Hive uses java implementation of regexp so the best source of knowledge will be: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html